# How to know when a new USB storage device is connected in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb

I want to know when a USB device is connected to the computer that my Qt application is running on (in Windows). In my main QWidget, I've reimplemented `winEventFilter` like this:

```
bool winEventFilter ( MSG * msg, long * result ) {
    qDebug() << msg;
    return false;
}
```

I'd expect qDebug to send at least something when I connect a USB device, but I don't get anything.

I'm guessing that I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the process here - this is my first Qt app!

Comment: Dont know if you still have this project of yours but I was wondering (as I've just started learning QT) if I could get a copy of it for reference. I don't know how to override the wndProc procedure yet and not seen good examples for it as of yet. Neither have I seen good ones for Platform invoke for Qt.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you may be missing is the call to register for device notification.  Here is code that I use to do the same thing, though I override the winEvent() method of the QWidget class and not the winEventFilter.

```
// Register for device connect notification
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE devInt;
ZeroMemory( &devInt, sizeof(devInt) );
devInt.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
devInt.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
devInt.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME;

m_hDeviceNotify =
    RegisterDeviceNotification( winId(), &devInt, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE );   
if(m_hDeviceNotify == NULL)
{
    qDebug() << "Failed to register device notification";
} // end if
```

NOTE: You will most likely need to change the values of the `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` to fit your needs.

EDIT: To use this code you will need to include the proper header files and perform the proper setup.  `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` requires the Dbt.h header to be included.  Also, the focal point of this code is on the RegisterDeviceNotification function. Info is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431.aspx)

Comment: Sorry to be dumb, but I can't make DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE work (error: `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE' was not declared in this scope). Do I need to include extra header files?

Comment: Don't be sorry.  I had a tough time figuring a lot of this out myself.  Hopefully my edit will give you some direction on how to use the code I gave.  It still may not be complete though.  I included the link to MSDN to give you a source for more info.  If I had more time, I'd try to give you a more thorough direction on how to implement it. This really should at least get the messages to your handler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working along the same lines but in C#.

you need to register your application with the system (look at the RegisterHidNotification() function). Mine looks like this: `

```
void RegisterHidNotification() //Register this application to recieve all USB device notices

        {
            BroadcastHeader dbi = new BroadcastHeader();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(dbi);
            dbi.Size = size;
            dbi.Type = DeviceType.DeviceInterface;
            **dbi.Classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE**;
            dbi.Name = 0;
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dbi, buffer, true);
            IntPtr r = RegisterDeviceNotification(this.Handle, buffer, (int)DeviceEvents.regWindowHandle);
            if (r == IntPtr.Zero)
                statusLabel.Text = GetLastError().ToString();
        }`
```

The most important part of the function is the bit I've highlighted in bold (or at least tried to). Defined as: `public Guid GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE = new Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED");`
Hope you can adapt it to your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reimplement [`QWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) and check for device connection :

```
    #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    #include <Dbt.h>
    #endif

    bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) {
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
        MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
        if (msg->message == WM_DEVICECHANGE) {
            switch (msg->wParam) {
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                qDebug() << "connected";
                break;
            case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                qDebug() << "disconnected";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
#endif // Q_OS_WIN
        return false;
    }
```

- Ref: [Developing multi-platform USB applications with Qt](https://wiki.kucia.net/doku.php?id=projects:qtusb)