# C/C++ USB drive event

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, usb

Regarding the Windows platform, is their an event I can look for to tell when a USB drive or any type of portable media us plugged in?

Comment: Even though [this article is about Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852752/how-to-know-when-a-new-usb-storage-device-is-connected-in-qt), the code in the answer is relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

You won't get such notifications without first registering for them. Use [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431.aspx)() to do that.

After you have registered your window to receive such notifications, handle the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) message.

Comment: -1, doesn't work because it's not needed. QUoting the linked MSDN article: "Volume notifications are broadcast to top-level windows, so the function fails if dbch_devicetype is DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME". USB drives (implementing Mass Storage profile)  are volumes.