# How to get USB notifications under linux / Qt?

Tags: linux, qt

I am newbie to linux and qt .

I want to get notify when usb get inserted and removed .

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for [DBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBus). I also think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python/471099#471099) could be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852752/how-to-know-when-a-new-usb-storage-device-is-connected-in-qt).
Maybe it can help. Btw. Since you are a newbie, I would suggest to avoid DBus if possible, as usually it is a pain in the ass.